# Insertion point using BinarySearch

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can i find an insertion point using binary search so i can insert an item in to a sorted array? The default `TArray.BinarySearch` does not provide such functionality.

Comment: Please read the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.BinarySearch

Answer (score 5):

TArray.BinarySearch does provide needed functionality - it finds proper index (`FoundIndex`) for insertion:

> BinarySearch returns True if it finds the element and False otherwise.
>   If found, FoundIndex contains the zero-based index of Item.
>   If not found, FoundIndex contains the index of the first entry larger than
>   Item.

Example: for (2,4,7) array and request value 5 it will find index 2 - you have to extend array, shift the rest of array from 2nd position, then insert 5 into 2th position.

Comment: Just to note: If you need to insert and delete items, it's much easier to use `TList<Integer>` instead, which has built-in support for doing so.

Comment: @KenWhite Sounds good but too limited. Most of the time I use Arrays.

Comment: @user3841593: "Too limited?" `TList<T>` has far more built-in functionality than `TArray<T>`. In what way would you consider it "too limited"?

Comment: @user3841593: Like Ken, I don't understand why you think `TList<T>` is "too limited". Are you confusing it with the non-generic `TList`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Who is talking about `TList` here? Question is clearly about `Arrays`.

Comment: @user3841593: You replied to Ken White that you found his proposal of `TList<T>` too limited, compared to arrays. I can't imagine why, unless you meant `TList`. Why use arrays, where you must code the insertion and deletion yourself, instead of a list, which already does this for you?

Comment: @user3841593: You were the one that said `TList<T>` was too limited. If you make such a statement, don't be surprised to be questioned about it. (And you replied to my comment that `TList<T>` would be a better solution if you need to insert/delete because of built-in support; because you use something doesn't automatically make it the right choice, and you shouldn't be close-minded about hearing of alternatives. The generic `TList<T>` is *much more flexible* than a `TArray<T>` if you're doing anything other than basic storage of values (which it appears you are).

Comment: "Too limited" makes no sense. However, there are plenty of times where an array is the right thing to use. When perf is critical, array access is faster than list access. Because list access does bounds checking. Not saying that is the case here, and many people optimise prematurely. But arrays are useful.